# Optimize two lists comparison

Tags: java, performance, grails, groovy, comparison

I have two lists (A and B ) of Contacts, coming from an SQL DB. On my application I need to display a comparison table of these lists, based on the contact name. If a Contact with name A exists in list A but not B, the details of contact A are marked green and next to it I have empty red space (for missing entry from list B. If a contact name exists in B and not in A, B is marked green. If a contact name exists in both lists, but with a difference in address, both contacts are marked yellow.

I am generating both a CSV comparison, and a paginated interface.

Currently, my not-so-optimal solution will first create a third list with all the contact names from A and B, removing duplicates. Next (if paginating) I will apply the offset + size. Finally with the remaining entries, I will search A and B by contact name (from new list), and call a comparison method that will tell me what color marking to do.

This was working ok for the datasizes I got, up to 4 -5k, with 2sec delays in pagination. Although I know this is not an ideal solution, but can't think of a better one. Also I got some new features (filter changes/additions/deletions) coming which will not work optimally with this method.

What other approach can I use to this comparison problem?

**Update**

Controller code:

```
    //createCompareList() based on parameters generate HQL query and pull contacts from Contact table 
        def listA = createCompareList(params) 
        def listB = createCompareList(params)

        def unionList = listA.collect{it.details.name}.plus(listB.collect {it.details.name})
        unionList = unionList.unique()
        result.unionListSize = unionList.size()
        unionList.sort()
```

And the rest comparison happens in GSP (this will be moved to the controller, and pass  something that requires less processing in GSP)

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th> C

ontact name</th>
                <th> List A </th>
                <th> List B </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <g:each in="${unionList}" var="unionName">
                <g:set var="listAContact" value="${listA.find {it.details.name.equals(unionName)}}"/>
                <g:set var="listBContact" value="${listB.find {it.details.name.equals(unionName)}}"/>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                    <b>${unionName}</b> 
                    </td>

                    <g:if test="${listAContact}">
                        <g:if test="${listBContact}">
                            <g:if test="${listAContact?.compareTo(listBContact) == 1}">
                                <td class="warning">
                            </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <td>
                            </g:else>
                            <g:render template="compare_cell" model="[obj:listAContact]"/>
                            </td>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <td class="danger">
                                <g:render template="compare_cell" model="[obj:listAContact]"/>

                            </td>
                        </g:else>
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else><td></td></g:else>


                    <g:if test="${listBContact}">
                        <g:if test="${listAContact}">
                            <g:if test="${listBContact?.compareTo(listAContact) == 1}">
                                <td class="warning">
                            </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <td>
                            </g:else>
                            <g:render template="compare_cell" model="[obj:listBContact]"/>

                            </td>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <td class="success">
                            <g:render template="compare_cell" model="[obj:listBContact]"/>
                            </td>
                        </g:else>
                    </g:if>

                    <g:else><td></td></g:else>

                </tr>

            </g:each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what u have tried so far show the code

Comment: I am explaining in the second paragraph.

Comment: If your code *works*, but you're looking for suggestions on how to improve it, you could try posting it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If it doesn't work correctly, it's not on-topic there, but you should still provide a demonstration here of what you've tried so far so that we can understand your situation more clearly.

Comment: I thought it will be easier to understand without the code, as that will introduce problems and variables which arent directly linked to this specific issue. But I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: programmer understand code better than words

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your data from a SQL database and your contacts are listed in different tables, you can perform a `LEFT JOIN` between their tables. For example:

```
SELECT A.*, B.id 
FROM ContactsA A 
LEFT JOIN ContactsB B ON A.id = B.id;
```

And retrieve its results using jdbc. These results contains all contacts belonging to `ContactsA` plus an additional column with the `id`, if the contact is present at list `ContactsB` or `NULL` if not. You can use that column to discriminate which entries are presents in both lists.

**EDIT**

If your two lists are extracted from the same table, you can always perform thr `LEFT JOIN` over the same table parametrizing the columns which split the entries into two lists:

For example, suppose you are splitting your entries by age, then the query should be:

```
SELECT A.*, B.id 
FROM ContactsA A 
LEFT JOIN ContactsA B ON A.id = B.id AND B.age >= 18
WHERE A.age < 18;
```

**END EDIT**

If you can't change your queries and you have already two Java `List`s: `A` and `B`, the best way to check whether a contact is present or not in both is to build a set from the shorter list and use that set to check which elements of the longer lists are not present in the shorter.

Comment: They come from same table, they are pulled based on some parameters provided before the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the comparation of 2 Lists use Sets. If you use as **hash value the name** of a contact you can check in O(1) if an entry is in a List. If it is, check the other informations.

```
Set<Contact> set_a = a.toSet
Set<Contact> set_b = b.toSet
foreach(e in (a union b))
  if(set_a contains e && !set_b contains e)
     //in a but not in b
  else if(!set_a contains e && set_b contains e)
     //in b but not in a
  else
     //in b and in a, check additional information for these elements
```

Should speed up the whole thing because the comparations are much cheaper

This results in an overall complexity of O(2n) of the comparation + building the sets. (One check for e in a and one check for e in b)

Comment: So, if I override hasCode in Contact to return name.hashCode, the result of the union will be unique Contact objects? What happens when a name exists in both a and b ?

Comment: a union b has only uniqe names but if you iterate about all elements in (a union b) and check if there is a occurence in a or in b you can find these cases. I just let the other cases out, but will add them now. If you tried this approach, let us know if it had a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your requirement properly but I think all that can be done at database end with queries.

According to me let db handle the comparison which will be pretty fast than jdbc code.

A and B are contact list and in DB both are present as tables

**Req1: list of contacts in A which are not present in B**

```
select id  <or required attrib> from A where id not in (select id from B)
```

This will be a list of ids which are only in A, append them in java list A with color green as you know there are no matching entries in B keep respective entries in B as empty

**Req2: similar stuff for unique contacts in B**

```
select id  <or required attrib> from B where id not in (select id from A)
```

exactly opposite stuff in both lists, now append this list in B with green color and respective empty entries in A

**Req3: same id in both lists but addr are diff**

```
select A.id from A,B where A.id=B.id and A.addr<>B.addr
```

this gives list of ids which are matching but has diff addresses, now append ids to both lists with color yellow

This saves comparison,coloring task which are bit heavy in java/pgming languages.

Comment: @Giannis: I just read your comment about single table then maybe in clause changes to parameter which you are passing, remaining should stay constant.

Answer (score 0):

My hint: use `SortedSet` as the accumulator. Thus you can save the calls to `unique()` and `sort()`, both of which would iterate through the whole list:

```
SortedSet unionList = new TreeList()
for( def a in listA ) unionList << a.details.name
for( def b in listB ) unionList << b.details.name
unionList // now it's unique and sorted in one sit
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution that I didn't think of from the beginning, was creating a map from the database list, using Contact.name as key. That made searching much faster, and with some changes on the comparison code, I got 58 seconds of processing down to 4sec.